# Message about "invisible" in R package learnr

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using the `learnr` package to buid a tutorial but in many exercises I receive this message in the Shiny app:

> Last value being used to check answer is invisible. See `?invisible` for more information.

What should I do to avoid this message in the output Shiny?

Thanks for advance!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample code and input that generated the message. Then we can use that to test and verify possible solutions. It sounds like the easiest way to avoid that is to not return an invisible object.

Comment: That means that you have called a function that returns a value but does not auto print it. To see the value, try `print(.Last.value)`.